# Recreating MasterMind game in Python?

Tags: python

EDIT:

Hi, earlier, I posted this question in a way that very lengthy. I am new to this site and did not know about the customs of posting. I will try again and be more specific with my question.

I moved a bit of my code into a tester file and this part returns an error. It seems that my count for blackpegs is not increasing because local variable 'blackpegs' was references before assignment.

```
blackpegs = 0
def test_guess(code,guess):
    for x,y in zip(code,guess):
        if x==y:
          blackpegs += 1
          return blackpegs
```

First, what does this mean? Secondly, how do I fix it?

Comment: Make questions bite-sized for best results. SO isn't a good replacement for a peer review / jam session ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the variable definition to within the function definition. I'm guessing you also want the "return" statement to be indented at the same level as the if statement, so that it goes through the for loop rather than exiting after the first instance where x==y.

```
 def test_guess(code,guess):
     blackpegs = 0
     for x,y in zip(code,guess):
         if x==y:
           blackpegs += 1
           return blackpegs
```